# XCode linking to OpenSSL library

Tags: xcode, macos, openssl

I've got a project that needs to link against the openssl libraries, although when i compile i have some issues.

```
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
```

initially told me openssl was not found, so i compiled it from source and copied the openssl directory into my project. The errors went away regarding the openssl, although I received a new error which stated:

```
applink.c

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'io.h' file not found
```

so this leads me to believe i'm not including the openssl library properly. can anyone give me some indication on how to accomplish this?

XCode version 5.0.2 / SDK = 10.8 / Target OS = 10.6 / i386 x84_86

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by linking:

```
libssl and libcrypto to target
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 'io.h' is an OpenSSL file. Are there any spaces in your Header Search Paths in the project's Build Settings? If so quote them like so: "My OpenSSL/includes"

Comment: i solved the issue by linking libssl and libcrypto to the target. thanks for the suggestions though :)