# Setting OpenSSL dependency fail in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, alljoyn

I am trying to run a sample code of Alljoyn, and I follow the tutorial to set my environment in [this](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/ios-osx).

When doing this command:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator
```

It shows this messages and fail:

- lipo -create '/Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/openssl.build/Release-iphonesimulator/*-libcrypto.a' -output /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libcrypto.a
  lipo: can't open input file: /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/openssl.build/Release-iphonesimulator/*-libcrypto.a (No such file or directory)

  - lipo -create '/Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/openssl.build/Release-iphonesimulator/*-libssl.a' -output /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libssl.a
    lipo: can't open input file: /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/openssl.build/Release-iphonesimulator/*-libssl.a (No such file or directory)
  - echo '***** removing temporary files from /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/openssl.build/Release-iphonesimulator *****'
    ***** removing temporary files from /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/openssl.build/Release-iphonesimulator *****
  - rm -f '/Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/openssl.build/Release-iphonesimulator/*-libcrypto.a'
  - rm -f '/Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/openssl.build/Release-iphonesimulator/*-libssl.a'
  - echo '***** executing ranlib on libraries in /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/Release-iphonesimulator *****'
    ***** executing ranlib on libraries in /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/Release-iphonesimulator *****
  - ranlib /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libcrypto.a
    ranlib: can't open file: /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libcrypto.a (No such file or directory)
  - ranlib /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libssl.a
    ranlib: can't open file: /Users/kenny/Desktop/alljoyn-ios/openssl/openssl-xcode/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libssl.a (No such file or directory)

  ** BUILD FAILED **

  The following build commands failed:
      PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script build/openssl.build/Release-iphonesimulator/crypto.build/Script-9038ACD812DCAC96004FA0D0.sh
  (1 failure)

It makes confused that it create the temporary file libssl.a and libcrypto.a and remove it. But then it fail to find it again?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: hello KennyYang, can you please tell me how did you got this error fixed, I am also trying to get this up and running and got stuck at the same position. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @MoeezAkram, sorry I didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Some of the library names look wrong: `-libssl.a` (notice the leading dash). Eventually, for the simulator, you will need an i386 (ARM) or x86_64 (ARM64) build. You can verify the architecture is present with `lipo -info libssl.a` and `lipo -info libcrypto.a`.

Comment: Here are some related questions... [Installing OpenSSL library for Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22692564), [How to add openssl to an xcode project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33341113), [How to include OpenSSL on an iOS project in a way that works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23955003), [XCode linking to OpenSSL library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20448909). etc.

Answer (score -2):

Hey so i had the above build issue when using the latest tag for openssl. If you use the documented one for ios builds it works fine

```
git checkout tags/OpenSSL_1_0_1f
```